# Python/Opencv Float converting to incorrect Int when casted

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, floating-accuracy

I am using OpenCV + Python to add an overlay image on a few videos automatically. For the most part my code works fine, except with collecting some heuristics from a given input video. I collect the number of frames and the FPS of the video using the OpenCV `VideoCapture.Get()` function and store then to variables respectively. The resulting numeric are `float` values which I then cast to `int`, but here lies the problem: the values drop by one!

The full code snippet here:

```
import cv2 as cv

inputnm = "testVideo.mp4"

# Load the video into memory
camera = cv.VideoCapture(inputnm)

# Get important heuristics
fps = camera.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
maxFrames = camera.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

print type(fps), type(maxFrames)
print fps,maxFrames
print int(fps), int(maxFrames)
quit()
```

This produces the output:

```
<type 'float'> <type 'float'>
60.0 401.0
59 400
```

Can anyone explain this to me why? I have tried converting it to `numpy.float128` and then to `numpy.unit8` but it still drops the values down by one. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

You have just seen the wonders of the floating point.

Python shows numbers as a close precision to their conversation from floating point, which is usually precise enough for visualization and in many cases also for computation, but in cases like yours the precision is simply not enough.

Use `round(maxFrames)`.

Comment: Yup, fixed. Strange that `print` rounds the float to the nearest decimal. I guess thats the real culprit around here.
`print 59.9999999999 # 10 decimals` produces `59.9999999999` and
`print 59.99999999999 # 11 decimals` produces `60.0`

Comment: yea, because cases like that aren't top level conversation problems. it lies in the way the compiler takes the values in and out, and that floating points values translate different in different conversations

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what is happening is your floating point variable is displaying as 60, but in reality it is probably 59 and some change. It will not display as 59 because python is smart enough to round up for our sake, (59.99999.. = 60). When you cast to int, you're truncating the decimals off of 59 which seems to drop the value by 1 (59.9999 => 59).

Edit: like the other user suggested, `round(maxFrames)` will round the value to the nearest whole number. Then you can cast to int and get the right result.